# What does BL mean, which a farmer can refer to other farmer?

Tags: vocabulary

> He argues that David should give up dairy; perhaps he could turn to **BL**?
>   ([lowfield.co.uk](http://www.lowfield.co.uk/archers/latest.phtml))

What does this abbreviation mean, which a farmer (Brian) says to the other (Daivd) farmer? The word is voiced at 3’40” in its BBC's audio of [2014-10-24 Friday](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/archers).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the abbreviation of a fictional Proper Name, and not related to learning the English language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your quote is from a summary of an episode of the BBC radio series *The Archers*.  A Google search for "BL Archers" reveals that BL is an acronym for **[Borchester Land](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/thearchers/posts/Borchester-Land)**, a fictional land development company appearing throughout the series.

Brian is apparently suggesting that David should try to make some sort of deal with this company, perhaps to sell his farm.